# Get foreign key records using Entity Framework and display in Angular

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using a database-first approach in EF, so everything was generated and I created an `Inventory` model class:

```
public class InventoryModel
{
    public int InventoryID {get;set;}
    public string Employee { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Localization> Localization { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the entity generated

```
public partial class xInventory
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public xInventory()
    {
        this.xLocalization = new HashSet<xLocalization>();
    }

    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public int Employee { get; set; }
    public byte Warehouse { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date{ get; set; }

    public virtual xWarehouse xWarehouse { get; set; }
    public virtual xEmployee xEmployee { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<xLocalization> xLocalization { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my GET without Localizations

```
// GET api/<controller>   
public IEnumerable<InventarioModel> Get()
{
   InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext();

   var query = db.xInventory
       .Select(i => new InventoryModel 
       { 
           InventoryID =  i.InventoryID, 
           Employee = i.xEmployee.Employee, 
           Warehouse = i.xWarehouse.Warehouse, 
           Status = i.Status, 
           Date = i.Date 
       });
    return query;
}
```

and here is my attempt to get the Localizations

```
// GET api/<controller>   
public IEnumerable<InventarioModel> Get()
{
   InventoryContext db = new InventoryContext();

   var query = db.xInventory
       .Select(i => new InventoryModel  
       { 
           InventoryID = i.InventoryID, 
           Employee = i.xEmployee.Employee, 
           Localization= i.xLocalization.Any(l => l.InventoryID == i.InventoryID)                    
           Warehouse = i.xWarehouse.Warehouse, 
           Status = i.Status, 
           Date = i.Date 
       });
    return query;
}
```

However this causes an error "unable to convert type to bool" and I can't figure out how to exactly get all localizations of each inventory because I'm relatively new to linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Any` method returns `bool` which obviously doesn't fit to `ICollection<Localization>`. If you need to get filtered localizations use `Where`

```
var query = db.xInventory
   .Select(i => new InventoryModel  
   { 
       InventoryID = i.InventoryID, 
       Employee = i.xEmployee.Employee, 
       Localization = i.xLocalization.Where(l => l.InventoryID == i.InventoryID).Tolist()                    
       Warehouse = i.xWarehouse.Warehouse, 
       Status = i.Status, 
       Date = i.Date 
   });
```